# Role of alpha-stability for subordinators

Tags: stochastic-processes, levy-processes

A Lévy process $\left\{ X_{t}\right\} $with values in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$
is termed a subordinator if it is a.s. increasing as a function of
$t$, i.e. the map $t\mapsto X_{t}(\omega)$ is increasing for every
$\omega$ in a set of probability 1. Furthermore, $\left\{ X_{t}\right\} $
is said to be an $\alpha$-stable subordinator, with $\alpha\in(0,1)$,
if and only if, for some $c>0$ and $\beta>0$, its Laplace exponent
can be written as:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\lambda X_{t}\right)\right]=\exp\left\{ -t\left(c\lambda^{\alpha}+\beta\lambda\right)\right\} .
$$

So far, my **question** is: why may we need a subordinator to
be $\alpha$-stable? Which is the main tool that $\alpha$-stability
brings about?